# creatiing a cupy array from python list is slow

Tags: python, cupy

I am using `cupy` to do the following operations and this is pretty fast:

```
import cupy as cp

shape = (256, 170, 256)

deformation = cp.meshgrid(cp.arange(shape[0]),
                          cp.arange(shape[1]),
                          cp.arange(shape[2]),
                          indexing='ij')
```

However, if I convert it to an array as:

```
deformation = cp.array(cp.meshgrid(cp.arange(shape[0]),
                                   cp.arange(shape[1]),
                                   cp.arange(shape[2]),
                                   indexing='ij'))
```

This seems to very slow or just hangs (I gave up after 5 minutes). I am not sure what I am doing wrong here.

I also tried passing `copy=False` to the `cp.array` call but this did not change anything.

Comment: Not sure if it's a copy/paste error but you are missing a `)` at the end of your `cp.array` call.

Comment: @jhomr Sorry that was a copy/paste error. Thank you for pointing it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't believe this conversion of list of cupy arrays to cupy array is supported.  If I make your `shape` much smaller, e.g. (8,8,8) I get a python error.

If we study [the documentation](https://docs-cupy.chainer.org/en/stable/reference/generated/cupy.meshgrid.html) for `cupy.meshgrid`, we see that it returns:

> Returns:   list of cupy.ndarray

The cupy [documentation](https://docs-cupy.chainer.org/en/stable/reference/difference.html#array-creation-from-python-objects) specifically says:

> Currently, `cupy.array()` or `cupy.asarray()` cannot create an array from Python object containing CuPy array (e.g., a list of CuPy arrays). Use `cupy.stack()` instead.

Using the suggestion there, this seems to work relatively quickly for me:

```
$ cat t6.py
import cupy as cp

shape = (256, 170, 256)

deformation = cp.stack(cp.meshgrid(cp.arange(shape[0]),
                          cp.arange(shape[1]),
                          cp.arange(shape[2]),
                          indexing='ij'))
$ time python t6.py

real    0m1.281s
user    0m0.608s
sys     0m0.492s
$
```

Comment: Ahhhh...I missed the second bit of that doc. Thank you!