# Convert a list of cupy array to comination of list

Tags: python, gpu, cupy

I have a list of cupy.array as follow,

```
X_train = [[[cp.array([[0., 0., 0.],
      [0., 0., 0.],
      [0., 0., 0.],
      [0., 0., 0.]]),
   cp.array([0.96376295, 0.4473439 ])]],
 [[cp.array([[0., 0., 0.],
      [0., 0., 0.],
      [0., 0., 0.],
      [0., 0., 0.]]),
  cp.array([0.08592631, 0.74990236])]]]
```

I want to change this list to this:

```
    [[array([[0., 0., 0.],
     [0., 0., 0.],
     [0., 0., 0.],
     [0., 0., 0.]]),
   array([0.96376295, 0.4473439 ])],
   [array([[0., 0., 0.],
     [0., 0., 0.],
     [0., 0., 0.],
     [0., 0., 0.]]),
   array([0.08592631, 0.74990236])]]
```

With numpy in cpu, I know that it solves with:

```
 X_train = np.array(X_train)
 X_train = [X_train.tolist() for arr in X_train for X_train in arr]
```

However, with cupy in GPU, I don't know how to solve that. It seems that it is different. Based on this link: [creatiing a cupy array from python list is slow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57257136/creatiing-a-cupy-array-from-python-list-is-slow)

Comment: The variable names in your final comprehension need to be changed...

Comment: From the expected output, it looks like you just want something like `X_train[0]`